# Youtube Playback Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I cannot understand why this isn't **working**.

I have checked the google extension **dev docs**, checked some **sample code**.

Checked other stackoverflow Question/Answers without any positive feedback/results from testing.

This extension is **very simple**

1. It displays a **popup** with an input text field and a button
2. on clicking it will send a message to the content script via **postMessage** to update the *document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate*
3. this will adjust youtubes or other supported (future venture) Video 
   Playback Speed beyond or lower than the default of 0.25, 0.50, 1, 1.25, 1.50, 2 or to an exact value like 1.4390
4. Easier and faster than using said console + devtools, etc..which speeds up the initial setup...

please help :)

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Youtube Playback",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Manage Playback Speed With Any Value",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "title": "Youtube Playback",
    "default_title": "Youtube Playback",
    "popup": "popup.html",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<script>
function setPlaybackSpeed(speed){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {action: "setPlaybackSpeed", "speed": speed});
    });
}
</script>
<div>
    <input id="text_playbackspeed" type="text" style="" placeholder="1" value="1"/>
    <button id="btn_updateplaybackspeed" style="">Update</button>
</div>
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.action === "setPlaybackSpeed" ) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = request.playback_speed;
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

Comment: Hey @woxxom would you know anything? heard you good regarding YT things...

Comment: You should be getting this error: "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive" on your popup.html....you have to separate the javascript to its own file ex. "popup.js"

Comment: Also, in content.js looks like `request.playback_speed` should just be `request.speed`

Comment: @JayA.Little sorry for the long delayed reply, I just updated the ticket with the correct code and project, etc as answer. Thanks for your tips, it got me to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution (its being a while however here you go, I forgot to update this thread)

### Overview

**This extension is very simple**

- It displays a popup with an input text field and a button
- on clicking it will send a message to the content script
- via postMessage to update the document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate
- this will adjust youtubes or other supported (future venture) Video Playback
- Speed beyond or lower than the default of 0.25, 0.50, 1, 1.25, 1.50, 2 or up a max of 4 times the original speed by using 4
- an exact value like 1.4390
- Easier and faster than using said console + devtools, etc..which speeds up the initial setup...

---

**Project Repo Hosted on Github at:**

- https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen/YT_SpeedMeUpExtension

**Or get the latest release via:**

- https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen/YT_SpeedMeUpExtension/releases/

**Or see latest updated Files below:**

---

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Youtube Playback",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Manage Playback Speed With Any Value",
  "homepage_url": "https://keybase.io/DeanVanGreunen",
  "repo_url": "https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen/YT_SpeedMeUpExtension",
  "permissions": [  
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "128": "icon.png"
    },

    "default_title": "Youtube Playback",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**popup.html**

```
<style>
    #text_playbackspeed {
        padding: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
    #leButtons, #findsMe {
        padding: 4px 8px;
        text-align: center;
        margin:0px auto;
    }
    #findsMe img{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 69px;
        height: 69px;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <input id="text_playbackspeed" type="text" style="" placeholder="1" value="1"/>
    <div id="leButtons">
        <button id="btn_updateplaybackspeed_minus" style="">-1</button>
        <button id="btn_updateplaybackspeed" style="">Update</button>
        <button id="btn_updateplaybackspeed_add" style="">+1</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="findsMe">
    <img src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/22296075" alt="The Developer" />
    <a target="_blank" href="https://keybase.io/DeanVanGreunen">Find me</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

---

**popup.js**

```
function setPlaybackSpeed(speed){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {action: "setPlaybackSpeed", "speed": speed});
    });
}

function getPlaybackSpeed(){
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {action: "getPlaybackSpeed"});
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(sender.tab){
            if( request.action == "returnPlaybackSpeed" ) {
                document.getElementById('text_playbackspeed').value = request.speed;
            }
        }
    }
);

document.getElementById('btn_updateplaybackspeed_minus').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text_playbackspeed').value)-1;
    document.getElementById('text_playbackspeed').value = num;
});

document.getElementById('btn_updateplaybackspeed_add').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var num = parseFloat(document.getElementById('text_playbackspeed').value)+1;
    document.getElementById('text_playbackspeed').value = num;
});

document.getElementById('btn_updateplaybackspeed').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    setPlaybackSpeed(document.getElementById('text_playbackspeed').value);
});


getPlaybackSpeed();
```

---

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(!sender.tab){
            if( request.action == "getPlaybackSpeed" ) {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "returnPlaybackSpeed", speed: document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate}, function(){});
            } else if( request.action == "setPlaybackSpeed" ) {
                document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = request.speed;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

**icon.png**

[image: Official Youtube Logo - Used by unofficial youtube chrome extension]