# How to click this kind of button (the DOM given) with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a chrome extension to click a button in the [example webpage](https://www.urlgot.com/profile/wzcEkpV). I got the DOM information of the interesting button. I want to click it with a button in popup html. The DOM of the button is given below:

```
<span id="dlIcon3">
<button title="Cloud download" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_blank" class="button button-rounded button-primary button-tiny cloudDownload" onclick="downloadFile(8680895,3)"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" style="font-size: 1.5em;"><span style="margin-left: 0.5em;">Cloud download</span></i></button>
</span>
```

The problem is the button doesn't have a "id" or "Name". So I could not using "document.getElementById(idx).click()". Is any other way to click the button? Thank you for your advices.

Here is my chrome extension codes:
manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "version": "0.0",


"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
  "clipboardWrite", 
  "clipboardRead"
 ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="test">TEST!</button>
    <script src="c2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

c2.js

```
function modifyDOM2() {
        var logout = document.getElementById('ytbInfo');
        var list1 = logout.getElementsByClassName('quality');
        idx="dlIcon"+(list1.length-1);
        var list2 = document.getElementById(idx);
        console.log(list2);
        //document.getElementById(idx).click();
}
document.getElementById('test').onclick = () => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: '(' + modifyDOM2+ ')();' //argument here is a string but function.toString() returns function's code
        }, (results) => {
            //Here we have just the innerHTML and not DOM structure
            console.log('Popup script:')
            console.log(results[0]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

bro, I had a similar question, I posted my working solution.

its also related youtube and chrome.

[youtube-playback-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200687/youtube-playback-chrome-extension) it's a simple video speed controller.

give the post a look and the source code as well, its available on github

Comment: Bro, thank you for your kindhearted sharing. Your speed controller is a great work. But I think my problem is more about how to make a click on website instead of processing youtube video. It is a work towards DOM manipulation as " how to fake a mouse click?" I wish there is a solution. Thank you again for your attention.

Comment: yeah, you need to have a listener which is attached to the web page and then you need to send a "message" to that background js from the popup.js

Comment: i see your edit. i only used that "function" var because i have a set, increment and decrement functions...

Answer (score 0):

I found an unsatisfactory solution to using

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button button-rounded button-primary button-tiny cloudDownload")
```

I have not find a solution to search the "title". Pity.